# How to add Annotation pin for source and destination in iOS using two color?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit

I am developing a small project, which will display the source and distance trace route, I did complete till that, now the thing is I am unable to add two annotation pin of different color for source and destination, suppose I am using red for source and green for destination.
This might be huge help for everybody who are learning and working.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use images for your pins or you could use a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` - `MKPinAnnotationView` and just change the `pinColor` property, it's documentation can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKPinAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKPinAnnotationView